# Flex 4.5.1 View State Transitions, how to optimize for mobile

Tags: apache-flex, optimization, mobile, flash-builder

I have decided to go the route of using ViewNavigator and having one view with 3 states.  Each state is a "page".  It runs just fine on the desktop but when compiled for mobile, the transitions between the pages is really laggy, even for the Samsung Galaxy S.  The phone has the 2.7 runtime and I recompiled my application with ADT 2.7, still no performance increase.

I have also tried cacheAsBitmapMatrix on all 3 pages, which are all contained in a VBox and that hasn't shown any significant performance bumps.  All I'm changing is the y component of the VBox for each transition.

Anyone have some suggestions?

EDIT: I have done some more research and I am now to the point where I have hardware acceleration turned on and cacheAsBitmap = true and cacheAsBitmapMatrix = new Matrix().  I am also using Stats.as to see the FPS.  I notice on my state changes I go from 25 FPS to 2 and then it goes back up again.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? What effects are you using?

Comment: Getting exact same issue on Blackberry playbook. Glad to know its not just me

Comment: Actually I decided to go a different route now.  I say screw the spark transitions, instead I added the Tweener library and it works MUCH better.  But to answer you question, the only effect I was using was the Move transition, on two spark components, a VBox and an image and all I did was change the y.  Not sure what the hang up was but Tweener handled the transition 100 times better so I'm just going to use that and just use the states in for designing the flow and just remove them for the final release.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VBox? You should only use Spark components in Flex mobile applications - MX components are NOT optimized...not at all.